# How to stream OpenAI chatCompletion response from Firebase callable Cloud Functions to ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, openai-api

I'm building a web app using ReactJS on the front-end, and uses Firebase Cloud Functions on the backend. I would like to use the stream capability of OpenAI's ChatCompletion API so that users can progressively see responses returning from the OpenAI's API. I deploy the OpenAI's endpoint on Cloud Function and calls them from ReactJS using the Callable SDKs.

However, my implementation so far always throw a TypeError:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

Code:

```
//At ReactJS's index.js: 

const Chat = () => {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

    const handleKeyDown = async (event) => {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            event.preventDefault()
            if (inputValue !== "") {
                const message = {
                    'role': 'user',
                    'content': inputValue
                }
                const updatedMessages = [...messages, message]
                setMessages(updatedMessages)
                setInputValue('')

                const result = await getChatCompletionWithStream({ 'messages': updatedMessages })
                const data = result.data
                // Get delta from response and create assistantMessageContent here...
                const assistantMessage = {
                    'role': 'assistant',
                    'content': assistantMessageContent
                }

                setMessages([...updatedMessages, assistantMessage])
            }
        }
    }

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setInputValue(event.target.value);
    };

    return (
        <div className='chat'>
                <div className='chat-log-container'>
                    {messages.map((m, index) => <ChatMessage key={index} role={m.role} content={m.content} />)}
                </div>
            }

                <TextareaAutosize
                    className="chat-input-textarea"
                    maxRows={3}
                    placeholder='Ask a question'
                    value={inputValue}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
                />
        </div>
    ) }
```

On Firebase Cloud Functions:

```
exports.getChatCompletionWithStream = onCall(options, async (request) => {
    var messages = [{
        'role': 'system',
        'content': systemMessage
    }]
    messages = [...messages, ...request.data.messages]

    return fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", {
        method: 'POST', 
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY}` 
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            model: GPT_MODEL,
            messages: messages,
            temperature: 0,
            stream: true
        }),
    })
})
```

How can I obtain the streamed results from the Firebase Cloud functions on the front-end? Note that I'm open to using HTTP Cloud Functions as well.

Comment: Hi, any help here?

Comment: You can't stream using Firebase Functions, I haven't found any server less option that can, but you can use Firebase Functions + something else that "listens"